# Android Layout disparity between API 16 and higher using radio groups

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

Trying to cleanup some layouts in an attempt to scale down from a layout designed for tablets to phone size. I've recently come across an issue with API's below API 17 which I do not understand.  More specifically, the layout does still work on larger DP devices but does not render properly on the smaller screens when an API below 17 is used.

The problem views are with radio buttons within a radio group inside a larger table layout.  The buttons themself render properly and consistently between APIs. The issue is with the text attached to the radio button.  Below API 17, the text is shifted significantly to the right resulting, in most instances, the text not being visible (I guess overwritten by the adjacent button's view).

Can anyone explain first off, why this happens and second, if there is a work around?  Nothing I've tried with gravity or other settings has any effect.  Near the point of bailing on support for anything below API 17 though that also means bailing on tablet users who would have no problems.

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="21.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        >
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_graph_underlying"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/graph_label_underlying"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="#ff000013"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_graph_volatility"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/graph_label_volatility"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="#ff000013"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_graph_daysLeft"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/graph_label_daysleft"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="#ff000013"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/graph_label_X"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="#ff000013"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/blank"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="#ff000013"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                />
```

THE PROBLEMS ARE IN HERE:

```
        <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radiogroup_graph_X"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="62"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_underlying"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:longClickable="false"
                         android:text="@string/graph_label_underlying"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>


            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_volatility"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/opt_sigma"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_daysLeft"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/graph_label_daysleft"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"

                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:singleLine="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_optPrice"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/graph_label_price"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"

                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_delta"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/opt_delta"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"

                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_gamma"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/opt_gamma"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"

                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_theta"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/opt_theta"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"

                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_vega"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/opt_vega"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_graph_X_rho"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="@string/opt_rho"
                         android:clickable="true"
                         android:checked="false"
                         android:enabled="true"
                         android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
                         style="@style/RadioButtonoaGreen"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
```

Also attached are two images

GOOD: [image: Good]
<sub>(source: [gedankenexperiment.dk](http://www.gedankenexperiment.dk/snowboarder/stack/good.png))</sub>

BAD: [image: Bad]
<sub>(source: [gedankenexperiment.dk](http://www.gedankenexperiment.dk/snowboarder/stack/bad.png))</sub>